# Does an HTTP status code 400 with Response "Invalid Credentials" Indicate the the HTTP Client Is Hitting the Endpoint

Tags: vb.net, http, visual-studio-code, https

I have a simple HTTP client which needs to get a token from an endpoint external to my company.  My belief is that the endpoint has been whitelisted for access, however my code returns BAD REQUEST.  This is confused when I run the equivalent as a request via VSCode, which returns a response of:

400 Bad Request but qualified with the content:

{
"message": "Invalid credentials."
}

Which would seem to imply that the endpoint is being hit.  Can anyone provide some insight into what is happening here.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because you got back a message doesn't necessarily mean you are reaching the specified endpoint.  It is going to depend on the setup of the external web service.

For example, a web API that I work on and maintain uses AWS API Gateway with a AWS lambda token authorizer in front of it.  All requests first go through this authorizer to see if they have valid credentials supplied.  If not, the *authorizer* will return back a 401 Unauthorized message, not our actual web API that is trying to be reached.  This is why you can't assume you are actually reaching the API with a test like this, since its not clear if the service itself it performing the validations, or something else.

You can *sort of* test this by trying some bogus endpoints out and seeing what you get as a response.  If you try a valid endpoint you know exists and then a bogus one that doesn't exist, if you get back the same 400 `{ "message": "Invalid credentials." }` response, you can say with *some* confidence that you aren't actually reaching the API itself, but rather something in front it (its not guaranteed though since again, it depends on how the external service is configured).